# Contact backend on before store process

Tags: plugin-events

I am using Joomla 3.9.22.

On the back end contact form, I want to make check on the submitted data. I tried to make a plugin but with no luck.

I have found the onSubmitContact event, but it does not trigger on the back end contact form. I used the code below:

public function onSubmitContact($contact, $data ) {
print_r ( $contact);
print_r($data);
exit;
}

I have also see here

https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

the event onTableBeforeStore but I can not see any example or doc about how to use it.

So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fun!  I was unaware of that event!

I have lots of uses for such an event, so I'm exploring it this nanosecond.  I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: onTableBeforeStore isn't in the API yet....maybe Joomla 4.0 only (it's in that API)

Exploring the contact events now, I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: OK, going to test this thing - what back-end contact form are you talking about?  The contact edit form?

The onSubmitContact and onValidateContact events ONLY fire in the front-end contact form.

Comment: @Michael Yes that's what I am talking about. I know about these two events firing on the front end only. I am looking for somethinf similar,  a way to make  some checks before storing contact data on the back end. Trying to find an event  that is best to place my check.

Comment: yeah that sucks.  It might be worth it to ask on the Joomla GitHub if this is something that the core devs might consider allowing into the API.  If they approve, it isn't really that hard to implement events into a component.